# External hard drive shutting down?

Tags: hard-drive, osmc

I've been setting up my Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B) as a home media center with OSMC and load contents from my external hard drive.

My problem is whenever the hard drive ([this](http://www.seagate.com/products/laptop-mobile-storage/laptop-external-drives/backup-plus-slim-mac/)) is connected to the Raspberry Pi it shuts off. Here is my setup:

- [SanDisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SanDisk) Ultra 16 GB microSD card
- ipTIME N100MINI Wi-Fi
- vPulse BT-T06 Bluetooth
- Samsung ETA-U90KWK charger
- Connected to a TV through an HDMI cable

Comment: I think that when you add the laptop USB drive that you no longer have enough wattage via your charger to power both the USB bus and the drive. I would suggest using a powered usb hub.

Comment: Assuming the drive works with another computer, this is likely a power issue. A powered USB hub should help.

Comment: So any USB hub is okay?

Comment: It needs to be a powered hub to solve the low current issue. FYI if you want others to be notified of your comment you need to prepend an @ and their username like so @beck we don't need to do this because you are the owner of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model A/B's I believe have a USB power issue even after they supposedly removed a polyfuse which limited the current to something well below standard (150-160 mA).

I have a small (1/2 TB) external HD that never reliably worked with a model B; I got a powered hub and that was fine.

With the A+/B+/2 models (and presumably the 3) you probably need to add

```
max_usb_current=1
```

To `/boot/config.txt` to get an external drive to work (e.g., that same one is flawless this way on a B+ for extended periods).  But that is no help with the older B.